# Is the PnP WPF/Silverlight Composite Application Guidance appropriate for role-based UI composition?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, prism

I'm developing a line-of-business application using WPF, possibly multitargeting SL as well. One of the requirements is that UIs be composed based on user roles/rights. For example, if the user is a salesperson, she shouldn't see any of the accounting components. If the user is an accounting clerk, that user will see some accounting components and a subset of sales components. If the user is an accounting dept manager, she will see all accounting modules, and a larger subset of sales modules, and so on.

I know that the Composite Application Library supports module-loading and UI composition (obviously), but I want to be sure that it has the flexibility to support this feature before I invest a big chunk of time in spiking it.

I'm not asking whether role-based UI composition is "baked-in" to the library (I assume that it isn't), but only whether it is a good fit for this model -- that I can intercept or configure the module loading and UI composition logic without any severe code contortions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Composite Application Guidance actually is a very good option for this.  By being able to easily assign content to regions, you can swap out your content by roles in a very flexible manner.

I personally think combining Prism with [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) makes this type of situation easier, though, since MEF allows for easier dynamic extensibility for roles.

I'd recommend [listening to Glenn Block's chats on Prism, Unity, and MEF](http://blogs.msdn.com/gblock/archive/2008/08/19/prism-mef-and-di-oh-my.aspx).

Comment: Yes, MEF. I have yet to delve into it. Can you give me a brief synopsis of what it brings to the table (well, I guess you already did)... how about a one-line synopsis of *what MEF is*. I'm afraid I don't even know what it is for. (I will listen to that podcast? to which you linked, but--ironically--I can't do it here at work.)

Comment: One liner: "MEF is a library that makes it very easy to dynamically add content to your application, 'extending' it at runtime".  It's basically a very clean way to make an extensible application (it's how the VS2010 extensibility works, for example)